# forkJoin not firing for graphql query with fragment

Tags: angular, graphql, observable, apollo, fork-join

I have encountered a problem similar to this:
https://github.com/prisma/prisma1/issues/1734#issuecomment-362576690

if i use fragment in my query, forkJoin doesnt fire -

```
forkJoin(...injectorObs).subscribe(result => {

  this.isHide = hide.apply(this, result);
  if (this.isHide) {
    this.hided.emit();
  }
```

exactly same code works perfect if i dont use fragment in my query, i.e.
i change this

```
  loans {
    ...loanDetailsFragment
  }
```

to use the field

```
  loans {
    loanNumber
  }
```

Comment: `...injectorObs` is it an array of observable ?

Comment: @micronyks yes it is